# Has anyone managed to use the 128 dimension embeddings from FaceNet to cluster faces?

Tags: neural-networks, conv-neural-network

I don't know if this is the right place to ask this question, but I have been fruitless trying for the past few weeks to get a cluster algorithm to run on the embeddings created by [FaceNet](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1503.03832.pdf). I have simplified the problem and I only have 2 faces from the [LFW](http://vis-www.cs.umass.edu/lfw/) dataset, but still I am unable to form clusters regardless of the method that I have used. I have tried K-means, spectral clustering and even the Rank-Order clustering but none seem to work.

So I decided to investigate using t-SNE, and this was the result that I got:
[image]

Regardless of the learning rate or perplexity value used, there seems to be no discernible clusters. This is weird as in section 5.8 of the FaceNet paper it seems like they are able to easily cluster the images. They mentioned using agglomerative clustering but no other details, although I am unable to reproduce the results.

I was wondering if anyone is able to shed some light on this problem, or even better if anyone was able use FaceNet to cluster facial images?